# Spring proxy beans from Interface

Tags: spring

What is the correct way to create proxy beans by interfaces?

```
public class JdbiRepositoryAnnotationBeanPostProcessorTest {

   private DBI dbi = mock(DBI.class);


   @org.junit.Test
   public void testIncompleteBeanDefinition() {
      AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
      ctx.register(JdbiRepositoryAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class);
      ctx.register(MyConfig.class);
      ctx.refresh();
      ITest bean = ctx.getBean(ITest.class);
      assertNotNull(bean);
   }


   @JdbiRepository
   public static interface ITest {

   }


   @Configuration
   @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ITest.class},
                  includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = JdbiRepository.class)})
   public static class MyConfig {

   }


}
```

I have tried bean post processor but It did not help me.

Edit:

I wanted to use component scanning by including annotation filter but it did not help me too.

Edit:

I want to create instances by another library which is creating proxy beans as this:

```
TestInterface proxy = factory.onDemand(TestInterface.class);
```

Edit:

I have extended `InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessorAdapter` for `JdbiRepositoryAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. 
I have been just logging currently. But I can not see my interfaces as a bean.

Please note that I have also changed my test code above.

```
public class JdbiRepositoryAnnotationBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor, BeanFactoryAware {


   private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory;


   public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      return bean;
   }

   @Override
   public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
      return bean;
   }


   @Override
   public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
      if(!(beanFactory instanceof ConfigurableListableBeanFactory)) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor requires a ConfigurableListableBeanFactory");
      }
      this.beanFactory = (ConfigurableListableBeanFactory) beanFactory;
//      this.dbiMap = this.beanFactory.getBeansOfType(DBI.class);
   }

}
```

Comment: `BeanPostProcessor` javadoc says `Factory hook that allows for custom modification of new bean instances, e.g. checking for marker interfaces or wrapping them with proxies.`. That is the right place to do it. What did you try to do?

Comment: What is a `static interface` in Java?

Comment: it was a inner static interface for testing purposes. Sorry for confusing

Comment: I meant show us the BeanPostProcessor you tried.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have edited again but my beanPostProcess is empty. Just logging currently.

Comment: InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor seems the right solution. I am checking it now. I will provide details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to ComponentScanning not PostBeanProcessor. ComponentScan is scanning only concrete classes that is why my processor did not work. I had to create a custom importer for interfaces.

Comment: what did your custom importer look like?